# What happens when passing a slice as an argument?

Tags: python, list, slice

I recently came across a problem with slice. Check the following code:

```
def clean(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = 0

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
clean(lst[:])
print lst
```

This code prints out `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

It seems that `l[i] = 0` inside the function has no effect. So I guess that Python is making a copy of the list when passing a slice into the function... then I did another test...

```
def clean(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        print id(l[i])
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
clean(lst)
print
clean(lst[:])
```

What surprises me is that the output is as follows:

```
140373225703016
140373225702992
140373225702968
140373225702944
140373225702920
140373225702896
140373225702872
140373225702848
140373225702824
140373225702800

140373225703016
140373225702992
140373225702968
140373225702944
140373225702920
140373225702896
140373225702872
140373225702848
140373225702824
140373225702800
```

This says that Python is not making a copy of the list but of the reference...
This becomes strange. Since the reference inside the function is still pointing to the original list object, why setting the value to 0 has no effect?

Comment: You can have two separate lists that reference the same elements. In fact, if you make one list from the other, that's _usually_ the case. On top of that, small integers are often interned objects, so even if you create the number `2` twice in two different ways they may end up being the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can have two separate lists that reference the same elements:

```
>>> a, b, c = object(), object(), object()
>>> lst0 = [a, b, c]
>>> lst1 = list(reversed([c, b, a]))
>>> id(lst0), id(lst1)
(4418696712, 4399675656)
>>> id(lst0[0]), id(lst1[0])
(4298830320, 4298830320)
```

And if you make one list from the other, that's *usually* the case. Slicing a list with `old_list[:]`, constructing a new list with `list(old_list)`, copying it with `copy.copy(old_list)`, etc.—all of these create a [shallow copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy). If you want a 2-level copy, you have to do it explicitly—e.g., `[copy.copy(x) for x in old_lst]`. If you want an all-the-way-down deep copy, use `copy.deepcopy(old_lst)`.

So, when you check the `id`s of the elements of the two lists, you shouldn't be surprised to see them the same. Ashwini Chaudhary's answer explains the consequences of this.

---

On top of that, Python is always allowed to "intern" immutable objects like integers, strings, even tuples and frozen sets.* Unlike, e.g., Java, you can control this by using `new` or not, in Python it's entirely up to the implementation, and you should never count on getting a new immutable object when you ask for one.

CPython only does this for a small set of values, but that includes a range of "tiny integers" specified at compile time, which default to -6 through 255 in 2.7. So, even if you did a deep copy—or even if you tried to create brand-new integer objects (e.g., `int(x*2.0+0.1)//2`), you would likely *still* get the same objects again.

---

On top of that, for literals of built-in immutable types, the *compiler* may merge two identical literals, so by the time it gets to the interpreter, what looked like two different equal values in the source code are actually a single constant value in the bytecode. For example, at the interactive interpreter (which compiles each statement separately), try this:

```
>>> 123456 is 123456
True
>>> a = 123456
>>> a is 123456
False
```

You aren't guaranteed to get those results, but that's what I get with CPython 2.7 and 3.4 on my laptop. But in a function, since a function definition is a single compound statement that's all compiled together:

```
>>> def f():
...     a = 123456
...     return a is 123456
>>> f()
True
```

---

In general, you also shouldn't count on *not* getting a new immutable object—except in the special case of a handful of builtin constants, like `None`.

---

Finally, be careful using `id` for tests. The `id` is only guaranteed to be unique during the lifetime of an object. So, it's perfectly valid for a Python implementation to return the same `id` for two objects if the first one has already gone away before the second was created. (In CPython, the `id` is the address of the underlying `PyObject*`, so if the same memory gets pulled off the object free list and reused, you get the same `id`.)

---

* In theory, it could even presumably intern your own custom objects if it knew they were immutable… but since there's no way it *can* know they're immutable, that's not going to happen.

Comment: Why "id(123456) == id(123456)" returns True?

Comment: @Wei: Do you really want to understand what's happening in the guts of your implementation that makes that true? If so, you need to specify the implementation and version, and we can dive into the source code.

Comment: I run the following code inside a module "x, y = 111111, 111111
print id(x)
print id(y)", it prints out "140448413205272
140448413205272" and they still have the same ids...very strange...

Comment: This is the Python version I use:   Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin

Comment: Now I roughly understand why my test fails. If Python does a lot of optimizations to my code, it cannot be guaranteed that using id() for two "equivalent" object always return two different values.

Comment: @Wei: Well, first, that code would probably give you the same `id`s even in the interactive interpreter, because `x, y = 111111, 111111` is a single statement, meaning the constants will get merged by the compiler. And _on top of that_, by putting it in a module, you're running the compiler on the whole suite at once, instead of statement by statement, giving it more opportunities to merge literals.

Comment: @Wei: Yeah, your conclusion is good. CPython doesn't actually do that many optimizations, but merging identical constants in the same compilation unit (a statement, a module, etc.) is one of them, and interning small ints is another. And that's presumably why Python has the more general rule that it will not guarantee that two equivalent immutable objects are unique.

Comment: The blog post linked from Chad Miller's answer, [Python FAQ: Equality](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/python-faq-equality/), covers most of the same ground, and covers much of it better than my answer, so if any of this is still confusing, try that.

Answer (score 5):

Slicing returns a new container when applied to lists, but the inner items are still the same. When you assign `0` to an index on a sliced list, you're changing value of that new container not the original list.

```
>>> lis = [1, 2, 3]                                           
>>> lis_1 = lis[:]
>>> lis_1 is lis     # Outer lists are different
False
>>> lis_1[0] is lis[0]
True
>>> lis_1[0] = 10    # This assignment affects only `lis_1` not `lis`.
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lis_1
[10, 2, 3]
>>>
```

The above lists contain only immutable items, when your list contains mutable items and you perform an in-place operation on that item then the changes can be seen in all the lists:

```
>>> lis = [[1], 2, 3]
>>> lis_1 = lis[:]
>>> lis_1 is lis        #Outer container are different
False
>>> lis[0] is lis_1[0]  #But inner lists are same.
True
>>> lis[0].append(10)
>>> lis
[[1, 10], 2, 3]
>>> lis_1
[[1, 10], 2, 3]
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types):

> Some objects contain references to other objects; these are called
>   **containers**. Examples of containers are `tuples`, `lists` and `dictionaries`.
>   The references are part of a container’s value. In most cases, when we
>   talk about the value of a container, we imply the values, not the
>   identities of the contained objects; however, when we talk about the
>   mutability of a container, only the identities of the immediately
>   contained objects are implied. So, if an immutable container (like a
>   tuple) contains a reference to a mutable object, its value changes if
>   that mutable object is changed.

Comment: Yup.  Try printing the id of the list itself - that should be different.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the ids of the integers.
integer have always the same ids.

```
>>> id(9)
5126256
>>> id(9)
5126256
>>> id(123)
5126872
>>> id(122+1)
5126872
>>>
```

Comment: This isn't quite true. `a = 1000; b = 1000; a is b` is False on my machine.

Comment: That is only applicable to integers from -6 to 255.

Comment: The reason behind is that integers are immutable. Therefore the Python interpreter may reuse already existing objects. This behavior is however implementation specific and not a must. You should subsequently not rely on this to be the case.

Comment: In CPython, the range of integers that gets pre-created and interned is configurable at compile time, and the defaults have changed a few times. Other implementations may have completely different rules.

Comment: I did another test with class. Check the following code "class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def clean(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        print id(l[i])

lst = [Data(1), Data(2), Data(3), ]
clean(lst)
print
clean(lst[:])", It prints out "4399320848
4399320912
4399320976

4399320848
4399320912
4399320976", why there ids are still the same?

Comment: @Wei: You've created two separate, non-identical lists with the same identical elements as contents. It's exactly the same as the first example in my answer.

Comment: @Wei: Is there another language you understand better? Explaining it in terms of, say, C++ or Scheme or whatever you already know might help.

Comment: Now I understand it much better. Making a slice actually makes a shallow copy of the container. References in the container are copied so id() of course gives the same value. If the reference in the container is referring to a mutable object and you mutate it, the change is "effective". For integer object, as it is immutable, you can only rebind the reference to another object, as a result, the reference in the copied container is changed, but the reference in the original container is not. That's why it seems that the change is not "effective".

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `id` or `is` with integers or strings. Python reserves the option to intern these values, which is to say that it does things like cache small integers and strings for performance reasons so that even two values that should theoretically be different objects may have the same id.

When these things are interned is left up to the implementation, so it should be treated as undefined behavior.

http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/python-faq-equality/

Comment: It's OK to use the "is" operator with None.  In fact, it's often recommended.

Comment: Yeah, this is misleading as written. First, using `id` for anything other than debugging object identity issues is a bad idea, and for that purpose it's just as safe and useful for immutable builtins as for anything else. `is`, on the other hand, is always safe (but rarely useful) to use as an optimization before checking `==`, and on its own it's useful with any value that you know is guaranteed to be interned (like `None`) or not to be (like any type you create yourself), it's just not useful for checking things like integer equality.

Comment: But the link is great (except for completely ignoring Python 3.x). The author does a good job of hammering home that you almost never want to rely on `is` except in the small set of common idioms (like testing for `None` or an `object()` sentinel) or special cases where it's obvious you wan it (caching, subtrees, …)—even after explaining why, he repeats the conclusion for those who didn't get it, and then repeats it again in a Conclusion section.